# How to add condition to loop

Tags: c#

I wanna check a value in array and if it exist return the value else return the message and read another value from array. add

```
 else
    {
      MessageBox.Show("This Item ID Does Not Exist");
    }
```

but the problem is when the the value is not in array, it want to show the message for 1258038 times.
how can I check the value (input) and if it exists, i can continue and if it does not exist in array , it returns back and read another value (input can be several values that must read one by one)

---

```
 for (int cun = 0; cun < ItemIdNumber.Length; cun++)
    {
      int Item_Id = Convert.ToInt32(ItemIdNumber[cun]);
      for (int yyu = 0; yyu <= 1258038; yyu++)
      {
         int weer = c[yyu];
         if (weer == Item_Id)
         {
           itemseq = yyu;
         }
         else
         {
           MessageBox.Show("This Item ID Does Not Exist");
         }
      }

      float[] i_ff = b[itemseq];
      for (int ii = 0; ii < i_ff.Length; ii++)
      {
    .......
```

Comment: Side note: please try to use good variable names/method names in code shared with other people. `ii` and `yyu` *may give an impression* that you don't care about your code.

Comment: it seems like my post is invincible.. -.-

Answer (score 2):

Use `break` to leave the loop early. You'll also need to change your logic a bit so you're not displaying a message in every iteration. This is just one possibility:

```
int? itemseq = null;

for (...)  // outer loop
{
    ...
    for (...)  // inner loop
    {
        if (weer == Item_Id)
        {
            itemseq = yyu;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!itemseq.HasValue)
        MessageBox.Show("This Item ID Does Not Exist");

    ...
}
```

I think with a little bit of thought, you could make this more readable.

1. You've got two collections to search - `ItemIdNumber` and `c`.
2. You're looking for the first value in `ItemIdNumber` that matches an item in the first 1258038 values of `c`.

Something like this `LINQ` statement maybe, although I'm not exactly sure what type your collections are. And I'm writing this free-hand, so it might not compile as-is. Should give you something to work with though.

```
var id = (from id in ItemIdNumber
          join cid in c.Take(1258038) on Convert.ToInt32(id) equals cid
          select cid).FirstOrDefault();

if (!id.HasValue)
    MessageBox.Show("This Item ID Does Not Exist");
```

Comment: maybe in this case, the message will still be shown 1258038 times when the item_id does not exist in the array..

Comment: yeap @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉. it shows the error for 1258038 times.

Comment: it still shows the error for 1258038 times @GrantWinney

Comment: Thanks @GrantWinney. may you explain what is ---- int? itemseq = null;  becuse i define itemseq as public integer

Comment: then i can change the name of this variable (int? itemseq = null;) to another thing @GrantWinney? since when i define it as itemseq. it shows an error which says this variable is exists in script. and i could not understand the ? after int.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int cun = 0; cun < ItemIdNumber.Length; cun++) {
    ...

    boolean found = false;    

    for (int yyu = 0; yyu <= 1258038; yyu++) {
        int weer = c[yyu];
        if (weer == Item_Id)
        {
            itemseq = yyu;
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!found) {
        MessageBox.Show("This Item ID Does Not Exist");
    }

    ...
}
```